# javascript + AST : parse html with script into html + script + css?

Tags: javascript, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I got some (potentially malicious) templates that mixes html + javascript + css 
 (both inline or as external links) in a "string"

```
<!-- well known libs -->
<link  href="//cdn/foolib.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdn/foolib.min.js"></script>
<!-- this is the core of the template -->
<div>foo</div>
<style>body {}</style>
<script src="//cdn/foolib2.min.js"></script>
<link  href="//cdn/foolib2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
...javascript code...
</script>
<div id='foo'></div>
<style>#foo {}</style>
```

I want to break this down as 3 "strings" (or other more convenient data structure) containing pure html, scripts, css
(A bit like the 3 windows you find in all the jsfiddle clones)

html

```
<div>foo</div>
<div id='foo'></div>
```

scripts

```
<script src="//cdn/foolib.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn/foolib2.min.js"></script>
<script>
...javascript code...
</script>
```

css

```
<link  href="//cdn/foolib.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>body {}</style>
<link  href="//cdn/foolib2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>#foo {}</style>
```

I guess I got to parse the string and go for an AST and process but could somebody clue me in.

Answer (score 0):

What you fundamentally have to do when you have nested langauge fragments, is parse the outermost language (e.g., HTML), picking up those language elements and capturing  fragments of other embedded languages as whatever kinds of substrings they are (e.g. script text), and then reprocess the fragments for the embedded language the same, recursively until you run out of nesting.

You won't necessarily get neat elements of one language, because people that do such nesting in text languages treat the inclusion mechanism like an arbitrary preprocessor.
So, in PHP files, you can find outermost PHP text (which largely looks like HTML), language inclusions which are actual PHP code. So you might have to to parse PHP-as-HTML,  real PHP code, and nested JavaScript.   If the "looks like HMTL" part happens to be script (e.g.,JavaScript), the transition points may be in the transition points may in the middle of a keyword or a variable name; I've see PHP code that alternates with Javascript to produce an "array" consisting of the JavaScript variables X1, X2, ... where x sub i is generated as a bit of Javascript followed by PHP that emits the numeric part of the id.

So you can't count easily on parsing these langauges as full programs, neatly bounded statements or even full keywords or identifiers.   That's going to make parsing really tough and reasoning about the parsed program even harder.  Consider the nice thought that the PHP may spit out a partial multiline comment for a script langauge, and then sometimes spit an early end to the or a late end to the comment.  How are you going to calassify the code between the early and late ends?

We do a lot of this kind of thing with our tools.  We handle some of these cases. We don't handle the really icky stuff because its... hard.

Comment: I'm not tryinng to parse PHP or any "templated" html (a la angular or others). I'm just looking for a tool that can parse html that mixes pure html + script (javascript only) + css and break it into clean parts. I've edited the question with the hope it's more clear now.

Comment: That doesn't simplify the problem much.  Imagine a JavaScript string literal sawed in the middle, with the first half with opening quote in one script tag, then some html, then the second half in a following script tag with it trailing quote.